# Singular or plural when listing items?

Tags: plural-forms, singular-vs-plural

> Now, we provide the definitions of A, B and C.

In the above sentence, should I put an `s` for word `definition` or not?

Comment: Are the definitions different for A,B and C? If so, the plural form is good.

Comment: You will still use the singular "definition" in a situation where A, B, and C have different definitions IF you include the word "each" (Ex. *"Now we provide the definition of each word"*) because now you are explicitly saying A has one definition, B has one definition, and C has one definition. That's the only time I can think of that the pluralization rules get a bit weird in lists.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer isn't really about whether you're listing items or not, but about whether there is one definition or more than one definition.  If all of the terms have one definition, then the singular, **definition**, is appropriate.  If there is more than one definition, then it has to be the plural, **definitions**.

For example, you might say

> The definition of *cover*, *conceal*, or *hide* is "to keep out of sight".

if they all mean the same thing in that context, but

> The definitions of *plaintiff* and *defendant* are as follows...

because *plaintiff* and *defendant* have different definitions.